# Fade in background image

Tags: wpf, vb.net, background-image

Hey all I am trying to fade in a background image on the main window.

Currently this is my code:

```
10  Dim storyboard__1 As New Storyboard()
20  Dim duration As New TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)
30  Dim animation As New DoubleAnimation()

50  animation.From = 0.0
60  animation.[To] = 1.0
70  animation.Duration = New Duration(duration)

90  Storyboard.SetTargetName(animation, "C:\Users\someone\Downloads\cabd.jpg")
100 Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, New PropertyPath(Control.OpacityProperty))

110 storyboard__1.Children.Add(animation)
120 storyboard__1.Begin(Me.Background)
```

The error is on line 120 with the Me.Background.

> Error BC30518 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Begin' can be called with these arguments:
>       'Public Overloads Sub Begin(containingObject As FrameworkElement)': Value of type 'Brush' cannot be converted to 'FrameworkElement'.
>       'Public Overloads Sub Begin(containingObject As FrameworkContentElement)': Value of type 'Brush' cannot be converted to 'FrameworkContentElement'.  scrollView

What am I missing in order to call the image fade animation on the mainWindow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use a Storyboard. Just call `BeginAnimation` on the target `ImageBrush`:

```
Background.BeginAnimation(Brush.OpacityProperty, animation); // C#
```

---

As a note, `Storyboard.SetTargetName` uses the `Name` of an element (usually defined in XAML). Setting a file path like `"C:\Users\someone\Downloads\cabd.jpg"` is pointless.

---

EDIT: You should of course assign a mutable Brush instance to the `Background` property before trying to animate it, e.g. an `ImageBrush`:

```
var bgBrush = new ImageBrush(new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\someone\Downloads\cabd.jpg")));
bgBrush.BeginAnimation(Brush.OpacityProperty, animation);
Background = bgBrush;
```

Comment: I get an error of **Cannot animate the 'Opacity' property on 'System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush' because the object is sealed or frozen.** when trying that.

Comment: So you didn't assign an ImageBrush to the target element's Background? Didn't you say you wanted to "fade in a background image"?

Comment: Yes but doesn't the mainWindow have a **Background** attribute already that can be used?

Comment: Sure, it has a `Background` property, but you have to assign something before you can animate it.

Comment: Can you show in your code how to assign it then? I only have the image assigned to a storyboard and we are no longer using that now.

Comment: Awesome that did it! Thanks Clemens!